# Is it possible to install tensorflow.serving using Colboratory

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, google-colaboratory

How to deploy tensorflow model using Colaboratory?
I am new to tensorflow , I have created a model and want to deploy it to the server but I dont have linux or Dockers so is it possible to do this using collaboratory.
Any alternative will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collaboratory is a research platform. It does not have a server component and neither should you rely on it for any production related task.

See FAQs [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)

Probably not directly relevant but perhaps still helpful is that Jupyter notebooks are not the way to go if you want to deploy a model.
A bit of development work to pipe the data in and out would be required. Ignore it if you already know this.